# Python 3.6 literal strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.6, string-literals

I'm having a hard time finding what can be put inside [literal strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

For example, I've seen this code on the PEP above, yet I didn't find any information above about what it does.

```
>>> value = 1234
>>> f'input={value:#06x}'
'input=0x04d2'
```

Is there a tutorial for understanding string literals better?

Comment: it is like using format but takes the values from the scope...more or less...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's new here is that you can just literally write `value` inside the f-string and Python will insert it.

The `#06x` part is nothing new and just a way to format numbers in hexadecimal representation. Python2:

```
>>> value = 1234
>>> '{:#06x}'.format(value)
'0x04d2'
```

`#` says to prefix the output (here with `0x`).
`06` says pad left with zeroes such that the output has at least length 6.
`x` is the hex format specifier.

You can read all about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).